# JSON keys with dollar sign

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to parse some json using `js` and `angularjs`, which it's path is: `item["sub:item"].$.url`.

Everything goes fine, until the `$` sign. I have tried to do ng-repeat with on `item["sub:item"].["$"].url` and `item["sub:item"].$.url` but nothing works.

Is there any solution?

Comment: `item.subitem["$"].url`

Comment: `$` and `_` are valid property/variable name characters. They can even be used as first character. I have a feeling something else is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ronen, I have tried both methods and they are working fine.
There must be some other issue.

#### Example

Kindly check console for output.

```js
(function init(){
    var data = {
        '$':{
         url: window.location.href,
            site: 'stackoverflow'
        },
        'name':'Hello World'
    }
    
 console.log(data['$'].url, data['$'].site);
        console.log(data.$.url, data.$.site);
})()
```

#### Updated Snippet

```js
(function init(){
    var item = {
        'sub:item':{
         "$":{
             url: window.location.href,
             site: 'stackoverflow'
            } 
        }
    }
    
 console.log(item["sub:item"].$.url, item["sub:item"].$.site);
})()
```

Comment: Hey @Rajesh, Thank you. Iv'e edited my question with the correct path, which still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {'subitem' : {'$' : "I'm  here."}};
a['subitem'].$ //prints "I'm here." in the console.
```

Your flaw is claiming that the given:
    "The path is item["sub:item"].$.url"

You need to prove this ^ by providing the full data structure you're trying to access.

In chrome you can print out the data structure with just "ctrl+shift+j" and type the variable name and press enter.

If the path were actually as you have it written in your question, you would have answered your own question already.